# In vital records at the Paris (France) Archives, what is the meaning of "ter" in the Numéro de l'acte (record number)?

Tags: vital-records, france

In the annual tables for records at the Paris Archives (http://archives.paris.fr/s/6/tables-annuelles/?), I have found some records where the Numéro de l'acte (record number) includes the letters "Ter" - for example "541Ter" (in 1946 deaths, 16th arrondissement, for Paul Georges Marie LECAT). Most other index entries just have a number (no letters).

If I try to find this death record using just the number 541 in the Actes d'état civil (http://archives.paris.fr/s/4/etat-civil-actes/?), the record with that number does not pertain to the the right person.

Does anyone know how to use the record numbers including the letters "ter" in the index table to look up the actual (death) record?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl: There's no link to the record, just a record number, which I can use to search through the register of numbered records. Record number 541 is for a different individual, and no nearby records are numbered "541Ter" (or pertain to my individual). I have searched the website for relevant instructions or FAQs, but I have not yet tried to contact the Paris Archives directly with this question.

Comment: I'm french, but unable to find the record either. I've sent a request via their contact form and will get back to you when I'll get the answer.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - The link in my original question was to the database, not the record itself. When I go to that link, and then search for deaths (Décès), arrondissement 16, year (Année) 1946, and Numéro de l'acte 541, I can look at a subset of records to page through. On page 25 (of 31), there is record number 541 - not my person. Not sure how to get to 541Ter.

Comment: Thanks, @bsfoo116. I actually sent a message their online contact form too, so hopefully we'll get some clarification.

Answer (score 4):

These may be references to deaths overseas, copied into the locality where the person lived. According to [Familysearch](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/France_Civil_Registration-_Vital_Records):

> The death of a soldier who died away from home is usually noted in the death records of the town where the soldier was born. Such an entry may be listed in the records a year or two after the soldier died.

If we look at the French database of military deaths in WW2, [Paul Georges Marie Lecat](http://www.memoiredeshommes.sga.defense.gouv.fr/fr/ark:/40699/m00523cfbc97af26), born 1920 in Paris, died in "Dora, Allemagne" in 1944.

Furthermore, others with index numbers marked "ter" in 1946 can also be found in the military records or otherwise to have died overseas:

Leonard Lucien Fatoux, 481ter: military, died 1944 in London
Philippe Lucien Fauquet, 156ter: military, died 1944 in Rouen
Alice Valentine Fleisch, 586ter: [Alice Valentine Spire](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000244660), née Fleisch, died in 1944 in Auschwitz.

Presumably these records were held in a separate volume which for whatever reason does not appear to have been digitised (or I cannot figure out where they are located).

Comment: Good tip, @njkt, thanks! The birth date for Paul Lecat in the record you linked to does match what I have from elsewhere, so it seems to be the right person.